# How do I determine the position of a tick in x-axis of a graph?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I want to get position(x,y) of a tick in x-axis of a graph to manual draw a line according it, please help me!
Please view below image to get my clearly question:
[image]

Comment: Tags belong in the "tags" box, not in the title.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Y coordinate of all x-axis ticks like this: `y = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt`. In your example image, this will be 0.

The ticks on the x-axis will have X coordinates between `ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale` and `ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale`, both inclusive, at intervals of `ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit`.

Of course, if you know ahead of time which X value you want to highlight, then that X will be the X coordinate of the tick.

The above is assuming your chart is selected/activated. Instead of `ActiveChart`, you can use `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart` or whatever the correct reference to your chart is.

**EDIT**: Just realized that the example you show is a Line chart. It won't be possible to do what you're asking on a Line chart. You have to change the chart type to an XY (Scatter) chart first.

Comment: I changed to Scatter chart but category of this chart is fix, this is not good for me.

Comment: What do you mean?! You can certainly adjust the category axis of an XY chart to mimic a Line chart's axis. If you don't want an XY chart, then you won't be able to do what you're asking, i.e. draw a line around/above it.